# jQuery doesn't work in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a site here: [mfm.treethink.net](http://mfm.treethink.net)
All the jquery works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but on IE8 it gives me errors and the banner at the top doesn't work (which uses the crossSlide jQuery plugin) and as well the image rollovers don't work with the colour change.

IE8 is telling me that the errors are on lines 53, 134 and 149 in the source, all of those lines are where the jquery function is declared.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

I am running jquery 1.4. Oddly enough, the other piece of jQuery I have on that page works, the artist browse/select menu on the right. But the banner and image rollovers don't.

Here are all the scripts I'm running:

## 1: the banner - doesn't work in IE8

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#banner').crossSlide({
      sleep: 5,
      fade: 1
    }, [
      <?php
   $pages = get_posts('numberposts=2000&post_type=artist&post_status=publish');

   $i = 1;
   foreach( $pages as $page ) {
       $content = $page->post_title;
       if( empty($content) ) continue;

       $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

       ?>

       { src: '/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo $page->post_name ?>.jpg' },

<?php $i++;

   }    ?>
    ]);
  });

</script>
```

## 2 - image rollovers - doesn't work in IE8

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $("ul#artists li").hover(function() { /* On hover */

    var thumbOver = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); /* Find image source */

    /* Swap background */

    $(this).find("a.thumb").css({'background' : 'url(' + thumbOver + ') center bottom no-repeat'}); 
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeTo('fast', 0 , function() {
        $(this).hide()
    }); 
    } , function() {
        $(this).find("span").stop().fadeTo('fast', 1).show();
    });

});

</script>
```

## 3 - the artist select - works in IE 8

```
<script>
    $("#browse-select").change(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
    </script>
```

These scripts were done by referencing previously made scripts, like I said I'm still new to jQuery. The second works in IE8 and the first one is the one that doesn't. I noticed the third one, the only one working, is written differently than the first two non-working ones without a function declaration at the top. Could this have anything to do with it?

Any help figuring out this problem would be so appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Wade

Comment: Please show the exact errors and the lines they occur in.

Comment: As a first hint: $(function() {}); is a shortcut for $(document).ready( function() {});, so the content of the function should be evaluated when the page is loaded.
Your third script is an event handler for the (dropdown?) select box and is activated upon value change.

Comment: Message: 'plan[...].src' is null or not an object
Line: 59
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://mfm.treethink.net/wp-content/themes/mfm/jquery.cross-slide.js

img.src = plan[i].src; is the line

Comment: And thanks Paul, that helps me understand a bit more about what's written but I'm not sure how to correctly write the first 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't post the actual JavaScript code but the PHP you've posted probably creates objects with trailing commas:

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2,}
```

Internet Explorer doesn't support that. You must generate something like:

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2}
```

Comment: trailing commas actually, but I think you're right. Changing the code so that JSLint doesn't complain fixes a surprising number of browser quirks.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure this is the problem because the thumbnail rollovers aren't working as well. I don't understand because I have that same rollover code going on http://www.treethink.com and that works fine in IE8 but it doesn't work on http://mfm.treethink.net

Comment: Actually, this might be right. I removed the code that does the banner and the rollovers worked. This could be it. I am looking at altering that php code now.

Comment: You are 100% right. I need to alter this php now so it doesn't display a comma on the last one.